# Is ArcMap's Mosaic Dataset primarily for display or can its component rasters still be meaningfully analyzed?

Tags: arcmap, image-mosaic, mosaic-dataset

Mosaic blends the areas of overlap between component images and adjusts the images to a common brightness.  Does anyone know if the final multi-band mosaicked image is still considered data, ready to be analyzed, or is it more like pansharpening or smoothing -- a cosmetic fix that removes some of the data quality?

Comment: Yes a mosaic dataset can feed into other geo-processing tools. Traditionally you would have merged say ASCII files into a single tiff raster dataset, but this would quickly lead to huge rasters that ArcMap would not be able to process. ESRI resolved this by creating the the mosaic dataset, it's superior in many ways.

Comment: Could you please verify not only that one /can/ continue in that way, but that one /should/ -- i.e., that there is negligible loss of precision in the mosaic blending?  In other words, being computationally manageable doesn't necessarily equate to being scientifically adequate, right?

Comment: No not really, as that would take a lot of time! I would recommend you experiment with it, maybe mosaic just two tiles and explore your workflow.